# ValueError: No escaped character for python shlex.split

Tags: python

I have a string as follows

```
mystring1=xcopy /Q /Y d:\\Program Files\\TestData\\*.* c:\\Program Files\\TestData\\Company name\\
mystring2=xcopy '/Q' '/Y' 'd:\tj\tjData\\' "c:\Program Files\TestData\\Company name\\"
```

I used shlex module as follows

```
mylist1=shlex.split(mystring1) 
mylist2=shlex.split(mystring2)
```

but I am getting an error:

```
ValueError: No escaped character
```

mylist1 value should be **[xcopy,/Q,/Y,d:\Program Files\TestData\,c:\Program Files\TestData\Company name\]**

and

mylist2 value should be **[xcopy,/Q,/Y,d:\tj\tjData\,c:\Program Files\TestData\Company name\]**

Comment: There should be quotes around your python strings, these are not valid python syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'm not sure to understand what you want to do but, on the first hand, I see a Windows user and, on the second hand, I seed a [Posix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) option in the manual.

So I thought : "posix=False" is for him.

And here is what it give :

```
>>> mystring1
'xcopy /Q /Y d:\\Program Files\\TestData\\*.* c:\\Program Files\\TestData\\Company name\\'
>>> split(mystring1, posix=False)
['xcopy', '/Q', '/Y', 'd:\\Program', 'Files\\TestData\\*.*', 'c:\\Program', 'Files\\TestData\\Company', 'name\\']
>>> mystring2
'xcopy \'/Q\' \'/Y\' \'d:\tj\tjData\\\' "c:\\Program Files\\TestData\\Company name"'
>>> split(mystring2, posix=False)
['xcopy', "'/Q'", "'/Y'", "'d:\tj\tjData\\'", '"c:\\Program Files\\TestData\\Company name"']
```

Character escaping is maybe not exactly what you need but, as I do not frequent Windows,I would venture no further on this point.

Edit: as I know it is not always easy to navigate in the documentation when you start on a subject, here are some links :

[shlex](http://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html#module-shlex) <= you shloud always RTFM. At least twice.

[Python Lexcial Analysys](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.3/reference/lexical_analysis.html) <= Could be not obvious, but will change your minds.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `shlex.split` documentation isn't very clear about what the `posix` flag actually does.

Answer (score 1):

The formatting of the input values is really bad.
Consider reading the formatting help.

Which string causes an error?
A first look at your input: The backslash character has a special meaning in Python strings.
So when the path is:

```
s = 'C:\MSDOS'
```

you have to write:

```
s = 'C:\\MSDOS'
```

The first backslash says: "Attention! The next character is not meant to have a special function", the second backslash is the character itself.

Have a look at http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/strings.html